# How are creature token cards used?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Me and my mom had a small conflict over this. Can you summon token creatures if you have the token, without a card effect that says to use it? I don't think so, but I don't know how to verify this.

Comment: Are you asking if you can just create token creatures at will? As in... I want an Elephant token, okay, I have one? Or is there a specific card you're trying to ask about?

Comment: More broadly, given your previous question about discarding, maybe it'd be useful for you to think of the rules like this: there are certain very basic things the game itself lets you do via the phases/steps of the turn (untapping, drawing for the turn, attacking/blocking, etc), and beyond that, everything that you can do is on the cards themselves. Want to discard a card, besides discarding down to 7 at the end of the turn? You need a card to let you do it. Want a creature? You need a creature card, or a card that produces tokens. There aren't really any "secret" things you can do.

Comment: I suspect the situation involved either using token cards as cards in a deck, or in trying to play tokens because they were [physically] available. I've edited the question to reflect this and voted to reopen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Can I summon a token?**

No.

The "standard" way to cast a spell is to follow these steps (this is an extremely condensed version of comprehensive rule 601.2):

1. Take the card out of your hand and put it on the stack
2. Announce the spell (e.g., "I cast [Elvish Mystic](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Elvish%20Mystic).")
3. Pay the costs of the spell

Tokens are not real Magic: the Gathering cards. They cannot exist in your hand. They do not have mana costs. You cannot add tokens to your deck. The rules simply do not allow you to cast them.

**What are "tokens", exactly?**

Tokens are markers that represent permanents.

> 110.5. Some effects put tokens onto the battlefield. A token is a marker used to represent any permanent that isn’t represented by a card.

**How are tokens created?**

It goes something like this:

- You cast spells and activate abilities.
- Spells and abilities create effects.
- Effects create tokens.

**What about those cards that come with booster packs that look kinda like real cards?**

Those are tokens, and again, they are not real Magic: the Gathering cards. They exist only to give you, the player, something to use as a marker. They usually look like the thing they are representing, which makes them far more player-friendly than, for example, a die, or a piece of torn paper. You can't exactly turn a die sideways to show that it is tapped.

Comment: Sweet thx now I can brag that I was right lol

Comment: I think your last point (What about those cards that come with booster packs that look kinda like real cards?) greatly clears up what could be a source of confusion for new players.